# REST API protect non-auth routes e.g. register, password reset

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, laravel-passport

I'm currently building an API using OAuth 2.0 for authentication.

I have auth working on all my protected routes but I am concerned about the unprotected routes such as `/register` and `/password/email`, these do not require auth so there's nothing (except some throttling middleware) to stop people sending requests from untrusted clients.

What is the best practice for shoring this up?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POST routes it will require the application token in each request so they won't be able to send request.

Comment: What do you mean by application token? The CSRF token?

Comment: Ok, I am aware of what CSRF is but that would involve both apps using the same encryption?